# What is the difference between = and ==?

Tags: python, operator-keyword

I would like to know what is the difference between = and ==.

I've noticed that `=` and `==` seem replaceable when defining numerical variables, but not for boolean variables.

Any clarifications would be helpful.

For example, for this program:

```
my_int = 7
my_int == 3
print my_int
```

This doesn't replace the value of the variable, whereas if I set

```
my_int == 7 
my_int = 3
```

it replaces the 7 value with the 3.

Please explain how these operators work.

Comment: `=` is assignment of value on right hand side (rhs) to left hand side (lhs), `==` is comparision between lhs and rhs.  You will see this by trying to `print(my_int)` after `my_int == 7` (assuming you had already declared `my_int` by giving it some value using `=` prior.

Comment: pseudo code : `a = 10` , `b = a` 
`# b is equal to 10`, `if (a == b) # true because a is equal to 10 and b is equal to 10`

Answer (score 9):

They're not interchangeable at all. `=` is an assignment operator, where you set the variable on the left to the value on the right. `==` is an equality test, where you are checking to see if two values are equal (it returns `True` if they are and `False` if not).

```
var = 7    # This sets var to 7
var == 7   # This tests to see if var is equal to 7, returning True or False
```

http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/ifstatements.html#more-conditional-expressions

There are some languages that dislike how similar they look, and they use `=` for equality testing and `<-` for assignment. I know that my professors liked to write pseudocode that way. I'm not 100% sure why `=` and `==` stuck, but that's the standard for C, Java, Python and more.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` symbol means **assignment** and can be changed as it goes along so for example first I might say `a=15` and now I want to change that assignment for my benefit to be `a=217621876`.

The `==` operator means **equals to** just like the regular equal sign in math. That cannot be changed. For example first I might say that 1+1==2 which obviously can't be changed 1+1 *is* 15 which can never be changed.

Answer (score 1):

This sets var1 as banana

```
var1 = 'banana'
```

This checks if var 1 is equal to banana

```
if var1 == 'banana':
    print('var1 is equal to banana')
else:
    print('var1 isn\'t equal to banana')
```

Answer (score 1):

`=` is used to **declare a variable** (i.e assigning a value to the variable [at RHS])
e.g : `a=10 , b= 100 , c= a+b`

whereas,`==` represents **equality check** (Boolean or y/n data type), i.e it check if `LHS` is equal to `RHS` and then returns `True` or `False`.
e.g :
`1+1 == 2` returns `True`,
but `1+2==2` returns `False`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **=** to assign a new value to a variable, such as

```
name = 'Yeremiah'
```

However, we use **==** to check whether a variable holds a certain value. An example would be

```
if name == 'Yeremiah':
    print('Your name is rather uncommon.')
else:
    print('Your name does not equal Yeremiah. Get out of here!')
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

Apparently, earlier `:=` was used for assignment and `=` was used for testing for equality. However, that changed to `=` for assignment and `==` for equality to save space. `&&` and `||` were changed to `&` and `|` for the same reason and then changed back again later.

I read that from the History section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language)

Comment: `:=` is still used in Pascal and languages like PHP have `=`, `==` and `===`. But we're talking about Python here.

Answer (score -1):

As you noted, there is the Boolean case. The == tests the equality of the operands, while = just assigns a value.

Answer (score -1):

With = you assign a value, example:

```
a = 14

b = 20

c = 34
```

And with == you compare a value with other.

```
a == b

False.

a + b == c

True.

if a == 14:

  print('hello!!')
```

Answer (score -1):

So when you are defining a variable you use `=` but when you are checking to see if a variable is equal to something, then you use `==`.

An example:

```
my_var=1
if my_var==1:
    print "yes"
elif my_var==0:
    print "no"
else:
    print "maybe"
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple:
"=" is an assignment operator which means when you are assigning  variable a value like bananas = 3.

It will give banana a value of 3 i-e "=" operator makes the L.H.S equal to R.H.S
.But "==" works in different way:

it is **comparison operator** if you want to ask **really bananas are equal to 3** you use "==" it will return the answer in **"yes"** or **"no"**. For example:

```
if banana == 3:
print("yes there are three bananas ")
```

Answer (score -1):

The = operator sets a variable equal to a value, whereas == is a comparison operator, such as something you would use in an IF statement.

Hope this helps, Luke.